# Adding Data to JSON Object

Tags: javascript, json

I'm having a hard time accomplishing something that seems simple. 
I'm trying to construct a JSON object to store some data. It starts empty and I parse through a file adding certain elements to it. Here's how I want my JSON object to look:

```
{"Items:":[
    {"Group1":[
        {"ItemType":"Type", "ItemName":"Name"},
        {"ItemType":"Type", "ItemName":"Name"},
        {"ItemType":"Type", "ItemName":"Name"}
    ]},
    {"Group2":[
        {"ItemType":"Type", "ItemName":"Name"},
        {"ItemType":"Type", "ItemName":"Name"},
        {"ItemType":"Type", "ItemName":"Name"}
    ]}
]}
```

Or I've considered doing it this way:

```
var itemsList = {
    "items":[
        {"groupName": "Group1", "Items": [list of items]},
        {"groupName": "Group2", "Items": [list of items]}
    ]
};
```

The name of the group isn't going to be group1, group2, and so on.

Here's how I've tried adding data to it.

```
itemsList.items.push(groupName); //Where groupName is a string

itemsList.items.groupName= "Name";
```

Or even:

```
itemsList.items[groupName] = listOfItems;
```

Which surprisingly worked better than I expected.
However, No matter which way I do it, when I try to use the JSON object it never works. When I output to the console it shows up as:

```
{ items:
   ['Group1': ['item1','item2','item3'],
    'Group2' : ['item1', 'item2', 'item3']]}
```

Which appears correct but when I do a JSON.parse() on the object I get:

```
{"Items":[]}
```

I believe this is because of the single quotes either needing to be double quotes or none at all but I don't know how to change that.

Any input is appreciated!

Comment: Actually, `items: [Group1: []]` _cannot_ look correct. An array cannot have the colon in the middle as its not a key/value pair.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just do:

```
itemsList.items.push(group);
```

where

```
var group = {"GroupN": [
    {"ItemType":"Type", "ItemName":"Name"},
    {"ItemType":"Type", "ItemName":"Name"},
    {"ItemType":"Type", "ItemName":"Name"}
]};
```

Comment: Thanks, this is going to work for me. I was doing this exact method but wasn't including the GroupName in the group variable. Thanks again and sorry for the simple question.